# A question about the interpretation of a certain probability about bounds of polynomials

Tags: distributions, logic

Consider a polynomial $p(z)= \sum_0^n a_i z^i.$ In the literature there are  numerous bounds about the roots of $p(z)$.Now once we prescribe certain dsitribution to the coefficients ,the bound itself becomes a random variable.Generally ,it might not be always possible to find the distribution of the bound .Suppose in certain cases we are able to find the distribution of the bound,say it is $F(y).$Then can we assert the following :
**For a positive number $c$,all the roots are less or equal to $c$ with a probability that is at least equal to $F(c)$?**
I would be highly obliged for any help/clarification in this regard.

Comment: It's difficult to decipher this post.  It seems to tell us you have a distribution of a collection of points in the (complex) plane and ask how to determine the distribution of the maximum modulus of those roots.  However, it doesn't really say that and it seems to say a lot of other things besides.  Do you think you could clarify your question?

Comment: i am sorry ,i mean the coeffcients have a  prescribed distribution

Comment: That's clearer but it seems to be trivial: you appear to be asking whether the distribution $F$ is the distribution.